# Global Variable in CakePhp not accessible

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code to set a global variable, however it is not being passed through to my views. Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $global_variables = array('miDateFormat' => 'd/m/y');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('global_variables', $this->global_variables);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it give you an error in your views? I've find that DebugKit, for example, doesn't show you the variables passed like that, but the variable does exists and has a value. And are you using `parent::beforeFilter()` inside  `beforefilter` in your other controllers?

Answer (score 0):

To save global variables use the Configure Class. For example:

```
Configure::write('miDateFormat','d/m/y');
```

To read the variable later in any place of your code use:

```
Configure::read('miDateFormat'); //d/m/y'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful to store more global variables and set to your views files.Create a file like custom.php in the Config folder and define the variables in that file like

```
<?php
$config['miDateFormat'] = 'd/m/y';
```

and load that file in your bootstrap.php

```
Configure::load('custom');
```

Now call that variable in the APPController beforeRender() function and set that variable

```
$min_date = configure::read("miDateFormat");
$this->set('minDate',$min_date);
```